# How to insert rows in a new excel file on a new folder in Sharepoint using Microsoft Flow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I'm creating a flow for my clients on Microsoft 365. This is triggered by form.  This create a client folder with the template documents one of them is a requirements excel file.

The problem is that I want to add the requirements that come from the form in this excel file. But as the folder and neither the excel exist "yet" I can not use the standard excel connector to add a row

Is there to work around this? or Am I just daydreaming ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In a perfect world you should be able to put some variable instead of final folder path and after creating a working flow on existing file, set the variable during flow execution.

And for example, with a `Create file` SharePoint action it works indeed.

Bot not with Excel's `Get a row` action which is known issue.

**EDIT :**
Finally found a neat workaround.

[image]

Comment: Hi @nervuzz Thanks for your answer. what is that table name ??

Comment: Default table name convention is `Table$` where $ is a number from 1 to n. Above table name was 'translated' by MS while modyfing the flow, do not care about it